# Using Cauchy's integral formula compute $\int_{\gamma(1;1/2)}\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^{2}-3z+2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I compute this? Do I use the factorization of $(z - 2)(z - 1)$ and do two seperate integrals with $n=0$ or do I use the factorization $(z - \frac{3}{2})^{2} - \frac{1}{4}$ and set $n=1$ whilst multiplying $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ by $-\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: What book is this from?  I've never seen the notation $\gamma(1;1/2)$ used to denote a circle before.

Comment: @AntonioVargas This notation is from Introduction to Complex Analysis by H.A.Priestley

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the ball $\gamma(1;1/2)$, which is centered at $1$ and radius is $1/2$, the only pole for the integrand is at $z=1$. Hence,
$$\int_{\gamma(1;1/2)} \dfrac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^2-3z+2}dz = \int_{\gamma(1;1/2)} \dfrac{\cos(\pi z)/(z-2)}{(z-1)}dz = 2 \pi i \times \dfrac{\cos( \pi \times 1)} {(1-2)} = 2 \pi i$$

You could also rewrite
$$\dfrac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^2-3z+2} = \dfrac{\cos(\pi z)}{z-2} - \dfrac{\cos(\pi z)}{z-1}$$ and note that the first term $\dfrac{\cos(\pi z)}{z-2}$ is analytic inside the ball $\gamma(1;1/2)$ and hence it integrates to $0$, while the second term integrates to $$-2 \pi i \times \cos(\pi \times 1) = 2 \pi i$$